# What are the technologies which are used in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

What are the technologies which are used in bootstrap?

What are the technologies which I should know to be able to understand and use bootstrap to create websites?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Bootstrap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546709/what-is-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any specific technologies you need to really understand to use Bootstrap except HTML5 and CSS3. In other words, you don't really need to master JavaScript or jQuery, etc. first. Although a working knowledge of JS would be useful. Bootstrap is very easy to use. I learned it pretty quickly just by going through some of the tutorials. One heads up though. To really use Bootstrap effectively, take some time to understand how Bootstrap deals with columns. This is very powerful.