# How to make Slider with value on a handle using Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider

How to make Slider with value on a handle using Bootstrap?
Or in worst case using jQuery, but Most preferable is Twitter Bootstrap.

[image]

In particular I want something like this [slider](http://jsfiddle.net/8KnJ7/3/) but on bootstrap

```
<div id="slider"></div>
$("#slider").slider({
    change: function() {
        var value = $("#slider").slider("option","value");
        $("#slider").find(".ui-slider-handle").text(value);
    },
    slide: function() {
        var value = $("#slider").slider("option","value");
        $("#slider").find(".ui-slider-handle").text(value);
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no sliders in Bootstrap, you have to use external library for that.

Comment: Can I use AngularJS?

Comment: AngularJS is just a framework for dynamic web apps. It is not related to sliders at all.

Comment: Hi, can I ask whether you managed to achieve this in the end? https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap-slider was the best I could find but no option to place text in between the range inside the slidebar

Answer (score 0):

As official bootstrap site cites:

"Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web."

Bootstrap is for responsive web design means you can create a mobile friendly and responsive layout. Refer to this for better understanding :[What is Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546709/what-is-bootstrap)

Now to actually achieve what you need , you can use jquery. Follow this you may find something close to you want : http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-range-slider/

Comment: Thank you! I prefer to deal with AngularJS, do you know if I can do it with it?