# How to increase height of menu bar in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How to increase height of menu bar in this code, 
how decrease column size and height 
how put a rich css for this design can anyone help me without any custom css.
in notice column data should display in that yellow color place only

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
              <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
              <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
              <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newcss.css">
            </head>
            <body>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
             <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                  <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <!-- Begin page content -->
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2 sidebar" id="side1">Links</div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Student Management System</h1>
              </div>
              <p class="lead">Home Page.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 sidebar" id="side2">notice</div>
              </div>  
            </div>

            <div id="footer">
              <div class="container">
                <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your actual requirement, but `menubar` height can be increased by adding following CSS. 
Note: This is a workaround, may not be responsive

```
.navbar{
     height : 100px !important; /*keep your own height here*/
}
```

Comment: <div class="container-fluid1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:lavender;">Student Management System</div>    
  </div>
</div>

Comment: i  changed nav bar as one top row. for this .navbar{
     height : 100px !important; /*keep your own height here*/
}

Comment: its not working.. that css will move the contents downwards

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mkyong/jbchky22/    how to fill the gap which is above the top section

Comment: [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) is an html, css, javascript framework that you can use as basis for creating web sites or web applications. More information can be said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14546740/1345854).

With that said after you have create your HTML, any changes, adjustment, or overrides, are done through a seperate CSS file (e.g. custom.css).

Comment: anyone check  thsi fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mkyong/jbchky22/   tell me how to fill the gap which is above the top section

Comment: The body tag has a 50px padding on the top. Check [https://jsfiddle.net/edden87/jbchky22/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/edden87/jbchky22/1/) with my adjustment. Thoughts?