# Make website fit mobile or any screen size?

Tags: html, css, mobile, scaling

I need help to scale this to any screen size (its for a project)
whenever I resize browser it messed up elements, can you help me so I can just copy and paste it back onto my editor

absolute elements get pushed off screen

```js
    $(function() {
                    
                    var documentEl = $(document),
                        fadeElem = $('.fade-scroll');
                    
                    
                    documentEl.on('scroll', function() {
                        var currScrollPos = documentEl.scrollTop();
                        
                        fadeElem.each(function() {
                            var $this = $(this),
                                elemOffsetTop = $this.offset().top;
                            if (currScrollPos > elemOffsetTop) $this.css('opacity', 1 - (currScrollPos-elemOffsetTop)/250);
                        }); 
                    });
                    
                });
```

```css
 body{
      padding:0px;
            margin:0px;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      cursor:auto;
      
      
      
     }
    .Paralax-1{
             background:url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/249360/pexels-photo-249360.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          background-size: cover;
          height:680px;
          
         }
          .Parainner1{
             
             padding-bottom:500px;
        
         }
     .Paralax-2{
      background:url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/187107/pexels-photo-187107.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb) no-repeat center center fixed;
          background-size: cover;
          height:580px;
     }
     .Parainner2{
             
             padding-bottom:200px;
        
         }
     .title{
      font-size:60px;
      text-align:center;
      margin:-16px 300px;
      padding-top:250px;
            border-bottom-width:4px;
            border-bottom-style:solid;
      color:rgba(42,42,42,1.00);
      font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;transition: color 0.5s ease;}
            
            .title:hover{
                color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
            
     }
     .subtitle{font-size:40px;
      position:absolute;
         top:328px;
      right:490px;
         z-index:3;
      text-align:left;
      margin:-16px 300px;
      padding-top:20px;
      color:rgba(42,42,42,1.00);
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      transition: color 0.5s ease;}
     
         .subtitle:hover{
                color:rgba(236,94,104,1.00);
            
     }
     .subtitle2{font-size:40px;
      position:absolute;
         top:328px;
      right:345px;
         z-index:2;
      text-align:center;
      margin:-16px 300px;
      padding-top:20px;
      color:rgba(42,42,42,1.00);
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      transition: color 0.5s ease;}
     
         .subtitle2:hover{
                color:rgba(55,100,211,1.00);
            
     }
     .subtitle3{font-size:40px;
      position:absolute;
         top:328px;
      right:190px;
         z-index:1;
      text-align:right;
      margin:-16px 300px;
      padding-top:20px;
      color:rgba(42,42,42,1.00);
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      transition: color 0.5s ease;}
         
     
     
         .subtitle3:hover{
                color:rgba(62,221,74,1.00);
            
     }
     #slide1{
      margin: 0px;
      padding-top: -50px;
      height:325px;
      background-color:white;
      
     }
     #slide1head{
      font-size:50px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
            -webkit-animation-name: c1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
            -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            position: relative;
            transition: 0.5s;
      
      
     }
     #slide1head:hover{
      transform: scale(1.2);    
     }
     #slide1para{
      text-align: center;
      color: dimgrey;
      font-size: 23px;
      font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;  
      
      
     }
     #slide1foot{
      font-size:26px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
      
     }
     .ih{
      z-index:4;
      float: center;
      margin-left:30%;
      margin-top:2%;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
            -webkit-animation-name: c1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
            -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            position: relative;
            transition: 0.5s;
     }
     .ih:hover{
      transform: scale(1.1);    
     }
     .ih2{
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-size: 55px;
      font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;  
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
     }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Wey Education</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Open+Sans|Oxygen|Raleway|Roboto|Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis|Quicksand|Titillium+Web|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <style>
    
        </style>
    <body>
     </section>
      
        <section class = "Paralax-1">
        <div class= "Parainner1">
               <h1 class = "title">Wey Education</h1>
               <h3 class = "subtitle">Aspire</h3>
               <h3 class = "subtitle2">Believe</h3>
               <h3 class = "subtitle3">Achieve</h3>
               
        </div>
        </section>
        <div id = "slide1"class="fade-scroll">
        <h1 id="slide1head" class="fade-scroll">Wey Education</h1>
         <p id="slide1para" class="fade-scroll">Wey Education is an educational services group that is passionate about the <br> transformative power of education. We believe that by driving up the academic <br> standards, we can improve the life chances and opportunities for young people.<br>We are commited to shaping the future of education as well as online learning, <br> and bringing an innovative approach to audiences across the globe.  </p>
         <h3 id="slide1foot" class="fade-scroll">Our current ongoing projects:</h3>
        </div>
        
    <section class ="Paralax-2">
         <div class="Parainner2">
             <a href="http://www.interhigh.co.uk/" target="_blank">
          <img class="ih" src ="http://www.interhigh.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/InterHigh_est.png">
          </a>
          <h2 class="ih2">The UK's #1 Online Secondary School</h2>
         </div>
        </section>
        
  
           
        
    </body>
 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you were a little more specific in your example code, or if you were able to create a more minimal example. Remember, SO is about getting help with a specific code question, not throwing a bunch of code up and asking others to simply correct it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the immediate parent of an absolute tag as a relative, absolute or fixed. Otherwise it will be set according to the first non static parent (body here)
,so set `parainner` class as relative first of all

Answer (score 0):

Try  [Bootstrap framework](http://getbootstrap.com/) its responsive works for both Mobile and desktops and yes tablets too.

also check [What is Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546709/what-is-bootstrap)

and [Click Here to learn](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp)